# Clustered consumption of messages

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Was hoping to scale out and distribute the queues for consumption across multiple machines. Is this possible? Most of the documentation I've found is clustering of RabbitMq itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can ( and you have to  ) distribute queues across the cluster to scale.

`queue` has stored to one node, and by default the queue is created in the same node where the connection is established.

you can read this post about:
https://www.erlang-solutions.com/blog/take-control-of-your-rabbitmq-queues.html

Comment: That's essentially what I am after, it's setting it up so the queue on the other machines know of the current connection to the rabbitmq if that makes sense, Ill amend the question.